# Python - cannot import name 'character'

Tags: python

I have this Python code in a file called customization.py

```
import sys
from easyread import *
import main
class character():

  def __init__(self, role):
    self.role = role


  def setRole(self):  
    print """
    What role do you choose?
    \033[31m Warrior 
    \033[35m Mage 
    \033[30m Rougue
    \033[33m Healer 
    \033[0m """
    charRole = raw_input()

    if charRole == "Warrior":
      self.role = "Warrior"
    elif charRole == "Mage":
      self.role = "Mage"
    elif charRole == "Rouge":
      self.role = "Rouge"
    elif charRole == "Healer":
      self.role = "Healer"
    else:
      sys.exit()

    wait(0.5)

    print "You chose %s" % self.role
```

I am trying to use the class in a different file called main.py

```
import sys
from easyread import *
from customization import character

char = customization.character(role = "")
```

But I get this error when trying to run it.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "main.py", line 3, in
>
> ```
> from customization import char                                                                                                                            File "/home/cabox/workspace/customization.py", line 3, in <module>    
>
> import main                                                                                                                                               File "/home/cabox/workspace/main.py", line 3, in <module>             
>
> from customization import char                                                                                                                          ImportError: cannot import name char
> ```

Comment: You have a circular import. `main` imports `customization` and vice versa. Look up how to resolve circular imports in python, there are various ways.

Comment: You should import `char` from the `main` module, not from the `customization` module.

Answer (score 2):

You could try removing the circular dependency.
In `customization.py` you import `main`, and in `main.py`, you import `customization`. Remove `import main` from `customization.py`.

Also, you import `character` from `customization`, so in order to use it, you only need `character(role = "")`.